# is wp_nonce_field field use the same protection as google reCaptcha?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, recaptcha

i am creating an registration form on wordpress, and i am using `wp_nonce_field` inside my form, i am wondering if i should include the google reCaptcha or not.

```
<form>
<?php
if ( function_exists('wp_nonce_field') ) 
    wp_nonce_field('plugin-name-action_' . $wpn_object); 
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WP codex:

> The nonce field is used to validate that the contents of the form request came from the current site and not somewhere else.

The nonce is basically an unique string generated for each visitor of your website. You'll use it to make sure forms are submitted on your website.

The reCaptcha is used to make sure bots can't spam you. It uses javascript and you'll have to use google's reCaptcha library: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

Comment: Thank you @ionv for your help